# How to align a label to left or right using RGtk2 package in r?

Tags: r, user-interface, gtk, gtk2

I'm using `RGtk2` to make a desktop application. I've created a label with an entry for input number but it's always aligned to the right side! I don't know what's wrong with my code. Please guide me how I can change the alignment to the left side. The code is given in below:

```
      inner_win <- gtkWindow(show=F)
      inner_win["title"] <- "Spreadsheed for Data Entry"
      inner_win$setDefaultSize(100,400)

      #Frame
      new_frame <- gtkFrameNew()

      inner_win$add(new_frame)

      #V Box
      entryBox <- gtkVBoxNew(show=T, spacing=5)

      entryBox$setBorderWidth(30)

      new_frame$add(entryBox)

      #H Box 1
      hbox_inner <- gtkHBoxNew(show=T, spacing=5)

      entryBox$packStart(child=hbox_inner, expand=F, fill=F, padding=0)

      #Label for age of woman
      aow_l = gtkLabelNewWithMnemonic("Age of Woman")
      hbox_inner$packStart(aow_l, expand=F, fill=F,padding=0)

      #Entry age of woman
      aow <- gtkEntryNew()

      aow$setWidthChars(10)

      aow_l$setMnemonicWidget(aow)

      hbox_inner$packStart(aow, F, F, 0)
      inner_win["visible"] <- T
```

The screen shot is shown in this image:
[image: Screen shot]

Comment: The only thing I can gather from all that is that GTK+ thinks your system uses right-to-left reading. I'm not sure what could cause that or how to fix it, but it might be a place to start.

Comment: I use English and Persian (which is right -to- left) in my system. If you have any idea about how to change it to left-to-right, please tell me.